# React, Redux, Filepond

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file-upload, filepond

My question... how do I upload files using FilePond but onclick, not automatically like it does out of the box? Also, since I need to take a number of other actions with theses images (like display them for review prior to upload) and since I need to add other data to the FormData that gets sent (plus dispatch actions to Redux).

Normally I would create a FormObject append the files and other values to it before POSTing it to some endpoint (with any custom headers needed). However when I inspected the FilePond instance it seems like the only thing I have access to is a blob... not the actual files. Is this accurate? Do I need to follow some special FilePond specific technique to get file upload to work?

FilePond's docs have a custom config value called "server" that appears to have access to an actual file in the more advanced examples so is this the way it must be done? I can't just grab the files (from somewhere that I do not currently see on the FilePond instance) and append them to an object for use in my normal "service"?

Any tips are appreciated. In a React app I want to upload a variable number of files onclick after appending other form data and setting headers (using Axios, ideally) and POST these files to an API.

Example from their docs uses a prop like:

```
server="/api"
```

I want something like (fake code):

```
server={submitImages} <-- this should only happen onclick of some button
```

where:

```
submitImages = (fieldName, file) => {
  const formData = new FormData()
  formData.append(fieldName, file, file.name)
  formData.append('foo', this.props.foo)
  const docuploadresult = this.props.uploadDocs(formData) <-- a service that lives elsewhere and actually does the POST
  docuploadresult.then(result => {
        // success
      }, error => {
        // error
      })
}
```

and my problems are that I don't see why this needs to happen in some special config object like `server`, don't see how to make this happen onclick, don't see an actual file anywhere.

I may be overthinking this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

FilePond offers the `server` property so it can handle the uploads for your. But this is not required, you can use [`getFiles`](https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/api/filepond-instance/#getting-files) to easily request all file items (and `File` objects) in FilePond and upload them yourself.

Add your own submit button to the form and use `submitImages` below to submit the files.

```
submitImages = (fieldName) => {

  const formData = new FormData();

  this.filepondRef.getFiles()
    .map(fileItem => fileItem.file)
    .forEach(file => {
      formData.append(fieldName, file, file.name);
    });

  // upload here

}
```

If you want to show image previews you can add the image preview plugin.
https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/plugins/image-preview/

Comment: Yeah its a working solution, but with this solution how would you handle upload progress (Loader)?

Comment: @AsimKhan you'd have to build that yourself outside of FilePond as FilePond at this point is not in control of the upload and you don't get individual file progress events.